# Is there a maximum number of allowed origins within HTTP header Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, http, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have around 130 white-label websites all on different domains but the forms on each all need to be posted to a common end-point.  I'm trying to achieve this by using Cross Origin Request Sharing.

With security in mind, I don't want to use..

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

And therefore I'm attempting to create a comma separated list of domains to allow, ie..

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.myfirstdomain.com,http://www.myseconddomain.com....
```

To achieve this on the back end, I've got a ASP.Net Web API solution set up and am trying to achieve the above by using the **System.Web.Http.Cors** library and defining these domains on 'application start'.

My 'application start' code looks like the following..

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var domains = "http://www.myfirstdomain.com,http://www.myseconddomain.co.uk .... about 130 domains more..";
        config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute(domains, "*", "*"));
```

The domain I'm testing this with is about 110 domains into that comma separated list, and when I attempt a jQuery ajax post, it first calls the OPTIONS method as expected (to determine whether the request is allow) but this returns the error **Origin http://www.mytestdomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**

However, if I modify the comma separated string to only have my domain, or even two or three domains, OPTIONS will return the 200 response and therefore allow the POST.

Does anyone know if this is expected behaviour or can see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I don't know about the behavior, but you could check the domain of the request and send a header back just for that domain if it matches

Comment: my first guess would be a missing comma or any other small mistake in the list of allowed domains (that you should definitely build from a config file/database/xml file/.... well anything but inside the source code :-)

Comment: The comma separated string is built from a database and string.Join, I just posted the hard-coded string for ease of reading

Comment: as said by @Bartdude, this might be an error in one of the allowed domains (even a trailing / could be causing issues). For validation rules, see for example : https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http.Cors/EnableCorsAttribute.cs#L178

Comment: got it, there was a trailing space in one of the domains!  Goes to show though how this could mess up every website if this manages to slip into the database, glad I found this up front, thanks..

Comment: Trim() is your friend then :-)

Answer (score 2):

The solution was that there was a rogue domain in my database with a trailing space.  This therefore causes issue when passed into the EnableCorsAttribute so be careful with your data!

Comment: You really shouldn't be returning ALL authorized domains in your response header.